# How do I access Ruby type names from within BasicObject

Tags: ruby

How do I access Ruby type names from within `BasicObject`?  I understand that "... common classes will not be found without using a full class path", but I don't know the syntax for specifying the full class path.

The code below fails because `Hash` isn't imported into `BasicObject`.

```
class Basic < BasicObject
  def flexible(data)
    if (data.is_a?(Hash))
      puts "It's a hash!"
    end
  end
end


foo = Basic.new
foo.flexible({})
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? What is a "type name"? What is a "class path"? Class path is a concept from the JVM, it doesn't exist in Ruby, and Ruby doesn't have types in the sense that it is normally understood (i.e. static types that are manifest in the program).

Comment: The quote above is from the documentation (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/BasicObject.html).  It wasn't clear what they meant, which is why I included the quote.

Comment: By "type name" I mean `Hash` in `class Hash`.   What is the correct term?

Comment: It is a *variable*, or more precisely in this case a *constant* (since it starts with a capital letter). Wow, the usage of the term "class path" in the official documentation is bad. I am not sure if it has an official name, but I would maybe call it a "qualified constant" or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your immediate question, you can access `Hash` like so:

```
if (data.is_a?(::Hash))
  puts "It's a hash!"
end
```

This will still fail for a different reason, which is because `BasicObject` doesn't include `Kernel`, so `puts` is not available:

> undefined method `puts' for #<Basic:0x000055c405afbc88>

If you do this as well:

```
class Basic < BasicObject
  include ::Kernel
```

or this instead:

```
::Kernel.puts "It's a hash!"
```

Then it should work as expected.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that including Kernel into a BasicObject rather defeats the point

Comment: `puts` in my example above is just a debugging statement.  I should have said `$stderr.puts`.